# Firebase - How to make adapters logic when data is update based on user logged

Tags: java, android, xml

I just tried to make a simple chat app with **firebase**. My application runs smoothly, it's just that I'm confused how to make a conversation balloon. `Left` (for the other person), `Right` for the user who is logged in the app.

For that I created `2 adapters`, where 1 serve to display the `left layout` and another adapter for the `right layout`

**Left Adapter:**

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MessageViewHolder> {

    private List<Messages> mMessageList;
    private Context context;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<Messages> mMessageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout, parent, false );

        return new MessageViewHolder( v );
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super( view );

            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_text_layout );
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Messages msg = mMessageList.get( position );
        holder.messageText.setText( msg.getMessage() );

        Picasso.with( context )
                .load( msg.getProfile_pic() )
                .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                .into( holder.profileImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(msg.getProfile_pic())
                                .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                                .into(holder.profileImage);
                    }
                } );


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }
}
```

**Right Adapter:**

```
public class MessageAdapterKanan extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapterKanan.MessageViewHolder> {

    private List<Messages> mMessageList;
    private Context context;

    public MessageAdapterKanan(Context context, List<Messages> mMessageList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_right, parent, false );

        return new MessageViewHolder( v );
    }

    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public MessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super( view );

            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_text_layout );
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final Messages msg = mMessageList.get( position );
        holder.messageText.setText( msg.getMessage() );

        Picasso.with( context )
                .load( msg.getProfile_pic() )
                .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                .into( holder.profileImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(msg.getProfile_pic())
                                .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                                .into(holder.profileImage);
                    }
                } );


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }
}
```

Both are different in the layout name call.

**My layout like this:**

[image: Left Chat for Left Adapter]

[image: Right Chat for Right Adapter]

**And this is my ChatActivity:**

```
public class ChatsActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private String mChatUser, mChatUserProfileImage;

    private DatabaseReference mRootRef, mMessageDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private TextView mTitleView, mLastSeenView;
    private CircleImageView mProfileImage, mChatProfilePic;

    private String online, image, mCurrentUserID;

    private ImageButton mChatAddBtn, mChatSendBtn;
    private EditText mChatMessageText;

    private RecyclerView mMessagesList;

    private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout;

    private MessageAdapter mAdapter;
    private MessageAdapterKanan mAdapterKanan;

    String URL_PROFILE;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_chats );

        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mRootRef.keepSynced( true );

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mChatUser = getIntent().getStringExtra( "user_id" );
        mChatUserProfileImage = getIntent().getStringExtra( "thumb_image" );

        /*getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE );*/

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
        setSupportActionBar( mToolbar );

        mChatAddBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.chat_add_btn );
        mChatSendBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.chat_send_btn );
        mChatMessageText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.chat_message );

        mChatMessageText.requestFocus();

        mMessagesList = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.chat_messages_list );
        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager( this );

        mMessagesList.setHasFixedSize( true );
        mMessagesList.setLayoutManager( mLinearLayout );

        mAdapter = new MessageAdapter( this, messagesList );
        mAdapterKanan = new MessageAdapterKanan( this, messagesList );

        /*mMessagesList.setAdapter( mAdapterKanan );*/

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled( true );

        final String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra( "user_name" );
        final String thumbProfilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra( "thumb_image" );

        chatUserPic( mChatUser );

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View action_bar_view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.chat_custom_bar, null );

        actionBar.setCustomView( action_bar_view );

        mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.custom_bar_title );
        mLastSeenView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.custom_bar_seen );
        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById( R.id.custom_bar_image );
        mChatProfilePic = (CircleImageView) findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );

        mTitleView.setText( userName );

        mRootRef.child( "Users" ).child( mCurrentUserID ).child( "online" ).setValue( "Online" );

        loadMessages();

        mRootRef.child( "Users" ).child( mChatUser ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mTitleView.setText( userName );

                online = dataSnapshot.child( "online" ).getValue().toString();
                image = dataSnapshot.child( "image" ).getValue().toString();

                if (online.equals( "Online" )) {
                    mLastSeenView.setText( online );
                } else {

                    GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                    long lastTime = Long.parseLong( online );
                    String lastSeenTime = getTimeAgo.timeAgo( lastTime, getApplicationContext() );
                    mLastSeenView.setText( lastSeenTime );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );

        mChatMessageText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );
            }
        } );

        mChatMessageText.setOnFocusChangeListener( new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );
                } else {
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );
                }
            }
        } );


        mRootRef.child( "Chat" ).child( mCurrentUserID ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild( mChatUser )) {

                    Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                    chatAddMap.put( "seen", false );
                    chatAddMap.put( "timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP );

                    Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                    chatUserMap.put( "Chat" + "/" + mCurrentUserID + "/" + mChatUser, chatAddMap );
                    chatUserMap.put( "Chat" + "/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserID, chatAddMap );

                    mRootRef.updateChildren( chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Log.e( "CHAT_LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString() );
                            } else {
                                mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );
                            }
                        }
                    } );

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );

        mChatSendBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String message = mChatMessageText.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty( message )) {
                    onError( "Message cannot be empty!" );
                } else {
                    sendMessage( message, thumbProfilePic );
                }
            }
        } );

    }

    private void chatUserPic(String id) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child( "Users" ).child( id );
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    final String URL_PROFILE = dataSnapshot.child( "thumb_image" ).getValue().toString();
                    Picasso.with( getApplication() )
                            .load( URL_PROFILE )
                            .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                            .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                            .into( mProfileImage, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {
                                    Picasso.with( getApplication() )
                                            .load( URL_PROFILE )
                                            .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                                            .into( mProfileImage );
                                }
                            } );
                } else {
                    String URL_PROFILE = "no_profile";
                    Log.i( "PAUL", URL_PROFILE );
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }


    private void loadMessages() {

        mRootRef.child( "Messages" ).child( mCurrentUserID ).child( mChatUser ).addChildEventListener( new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                Messages message = dataSnapshot.getValue( Messages.class );

                String currentUserID = message.current_user_id.toString();

                if(currentUserID.equals( mCurrentUserID )) {
                    mMessagesList.setAdapter( mAdapterKanan );
                    messagesList.add( message );
                    mAdapterKanan.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.i( "PAUL", "USER LOGGED SAMA DENGAN YG SEDANG LOGIN" );
                } else {
                    Log.i( "PAUL", "USER LOGGED TIDAK SAMA DENGAN YG SEDANG LOGIN" );
                    mMessagesList.setAdapter( mAdapter );
                    messagesList.add( message );
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                /*mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message, String profile_pic) {

        String current_user_ref = "Messages" + "/" + mCurrentUserID + "/" + mChatUser;
        String chat_user_ref = "Messages" + "/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserID;

        DatabaseReference user_message_push = mRootRef.child( "Messages" )
                .child( mCurrentUserID ).child( mChatUser ).push();


        String push_id = user_message_push.getKey();

        Map messageMap = new HashMap();
        messageMap.put( "message", message );
        messageMap.put( "seen", false );
        messageMap.put( "type", "text" );
        messageMap.put( "time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP );
        messageMap.put( "profile_pic", profile_pic );
        messageMap.put( "current_user_id", mCurrentUserID );


        Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
        messageUserMap.put( current_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap );
        messageUserMap.put( chat_user_ref + "/" + push_id, messageMap );

        mRootRef.updateChildren( messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    mChatMessageText.setText( "" );
                    Log.e( "SEND_MESSAGE_CHAT", databaseError.getMessage().toString() );
                } else {
                    mChatMessageText.setText( "" );
                    mMessagesList.scrollToPosition( mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1 );
                }
            }
        } );

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mRootRef.child( "Users" ).child( mCurrentUserID ).child( "online" ).setValue( "Online" );
        mMessagesList.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition( mLinearLayout.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1000 );
    }

}
```

You see in loadMessages() method, you can see my logic like

```
   String currentUserID = message.current_user_id.toString();

   if(currentUserID.equals( mCurrentUserID )) {
        mMessagesList.setAdapter( mAdapterKanan );
        messagesList.add( message );
        mAdapterKanan.notifyDataSetChanged();
   } else {
        mMessagesList.setAdapter( mAdapter );
        messagesList.add( message );
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

After I tried on two devices, the results I got did not match what I expected.

**Vickys Device :**
[image: Vickys Device]

**Berthos Device :**
[image: Berthos Device]

How to make layout as in chat generally? Please advise for layout logic

Answer (score 0):

You dont have need to take two adapter.Only create one adapter like this view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/activity_account_setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/recievemessageLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="hi i m sender" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/sendingMessageLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recievemessageLayout">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewSender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewSender"
                android:text="hi i m reciver" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After that according to the logic set the data  in the  reciveMessageLayout and sending messagelayout in the onBindViewHolder method of the adapter like this:

```
String currentUserID = message.current_user_id.toString();



    if(currentUserID.equals( mCurrentUserID )) {
        //  set data in the sending message layout
       } else {
         //  set data in the receving message layout
      }
```

Hope this will help you out..

Comment: Okz bertho and after that please tell me was it helpfull for you or not.

Comment: Hi @Deepak After I tried, I was a bit confused using the adapter for 2 elements. `RecievemessageLayout` and `sendingMessageLayout`. For each data loop from the database, how the adapter displays the data to the `recievemessageLayout` element while `sendingMessageLayout` is left blank when the sender is logged in, or vice versa. Whereas in one layout there are 2 elements of this. Can you help me give an example of 1 adapter for this case?

Comment: First hide the visibility for both the sending and receiving layout in the xml.After sending the first message make the visibilty of the sendinglayout visible and after recieving the message make the visibilty of the recievemessagelayout visible

Comment: Hi @Deepak I found a little problem. When there are 2 elements that are mutually displayed and hidden. In my case, the two elements. I use are `CircleImageView` and `TextView`. And both of these emelent have the same `ID` because one for `recievemessageLayout` and one for `sendingMessageLayout`. How to handle it? Because the adapter only recognizes one `ID` to load the data.

Comment: See the xml file once again i have take one image view and textView in recievemessagelayout and one imageView and textView in sendingMessageLayout.

Comment: you have to give different id name to all the imageView and textView like this: imageViewSending,textViewSending,imageViewRecieve and textViewRecieve. You dont have to need to hide and show all the imageView and textView , just hide and show the rootlayout of the imageView and textView i.e hide and show sendingMessageLayout and recievemessageLayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151121/discussion-between-bertho-joris-and-deepak-rana).